# Selecting a whole row with specific distinct columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this example table, with example data:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| OriginalBeginDate | OriginalEndDate | Start Date |  End Date  |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-08-01 | 2015-08-31 |
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-30 |
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-31 |
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-11-01 | 2015-11-30 |
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-12-01 | 2015-12-31 |
| 2015-07-01        | 2015-12-31      | 2015-08-01 | 2015-08-31 |
| 2015-07-01        | 2015-12-31      | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-30 |
| 2015-07-01        | 2015-12-31      | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-31 |
| 2015-07-01        | 2015-12-31      | 2015-11-01 | 2015-11-30 |
| 2015-07-01        | 2015-12-31      | 2015-12-01 | 2015-12-31 |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

If you notice, there is a set of 5 'Start Date's and 'End Date's repeated because the 'OriginalBeginDate' and 'OriginalEndDate' has two 'sets'.

I need to have only one set of the last two columns (distinct values of them).

This is what the output needs to look like:

```
| OriginalBeginDate | OriginalEndDate | Start Date |  End Date  |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-08-01 | 2015-08-31 |
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-30 |
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-31 |
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-11-01 | 2015-11-30 |
| 2015-06-01        | 2015-06-30      | 2015-12-01 | 2015-12-31 |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

If I run

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM myTable
```

I get the whole table. If I run

```
SELECT DISTINCT [START DATE], [END DATE] FROM myTable
```

I don't get all 4 columns, which, I need.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: On what condition you are skipping second set?

Comment: Can you try adding where clause like OriginalBeginDate ='2015-06-01' ?

Comment: Though the requirement was not specified to me, I would imagine it would be that we want to keep the set with the earliest 'OriginalBeginDate'

Comment: Vinayak, I can not do that because I will not always know what data is in the table. 

Ideally, this query is executed by an application that a customer uses, and the result is just sent back to them. This means that the actual result that is gotten back is gotten back from a black box, so to speak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add some grouping with `MIN` to take the lowest values of the other columns, which seems like what you're after:

```
SELECT MIN(OriginalBeginDate) as OriginalBeginDate, 
       MIN(OriginalEndDate) as OriginalEndDate, 
       [START DATE], 
       [END DATE] 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY [START DATE], [END DATE]
```

Comment: Too soon to mark this answer as correct, but I can see this working. I will check and let you know.

Comment: I didn't notice you have posted an answer before.. I will delete my answer, +1 for quick response.

Comment: @AnujTripathi, your answer is different to this. `Min()` vs `Max()`

Comment: @Kaf but they both means same as their only purpose is to allow us to do group by on start date and end date. May be that's why I got down vote. But thanks anyways for your support, I appreciate it :)

Comment: @AnujTripathi you don't have to delete,as Kaf says it's slightly different. I used MIN based on the desired output though as the OP has taken the lowest values of the additional columns.

Comment: @AnujTripathi: I agree, you got the logic correct. BTW, it wasn't me down voted you.

Comment: @Tanner I agree and I voted because you deserve it. Moreover, OP is satisfied with correct results.
 Kaf :) Never mind. I knew that you didn't. Hope to see you around more.

Answer (score 4):

You can try below by grouping data based on start date and end date

```
 DECLARE @mytable TABLE
        (
          OriginalBeginDate DATE ,
          OriginalEndDate DATE NOT NULL ,
          Start_Date DATE NOT NULL ,
          End_Date DATE NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO @mytable(OriginalBeginDate,OriginalEndDate,Start_Date,End_Date) 
VALUES ('2015-06-01','2015-06-30','2015-08-01','2015-08-31')
     , ('2015-06-01','2015-06-30','2015-09-01','2015-09-30')
     , ('2015-06-01','2015-06-30','2015-10-01','2015-10-31')
     , ('2015-06-01','2015-06-30','2015-11-01','2015-11-30')
     , ('2015-06-01','2015-06-30','2015-12-01','2015-12-31')
     , ('2015-07-01','2015-12-31','2015-08-01','2015-08-31')
     , ('2015-07-01','2015-12-31','2015-09-01','2015-09-30')
     , ('2015-07-01','2015-12-31','2015-10-01','2015-10-31')
     , ('2015-07-01','2015-12-31','2015-11-01','2015-11-30')
     , ('2015-07-01','2015-12-31','2015-12-01','2015-12-31')

SELECT MIN(OriginalBeginDate), MIN(OriginalEndDate), Start_Date, End_Date
FROM @mytable
GROUP BY Start_Date, End_Date
```

Comment: @Balm Yes, I used http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm to convert it to SQL statement. :) But I have simplified it now

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding a condition to your query to only return the row with the lowest `OriginalBeginDate` value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 OriginalBeginDate 
                  FROM myTable t2 
                  WHERE t2.[Start Date] = myTable.[Start Date]
                  AND t2.[End Date] = myTable.[End Date]
                  AND t2.OriginalBeginDate = myTable.OriginalBeginDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use:

Edit: OVER mus use partition BEFORE OrderBy...

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Start Date] ORDER BY OriginalBeginDate) AS Inx1
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [End Date] ORDER BY OriginalEndDate) AS Inx2
      ,*
FROM @myTable
) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.Inx1=1 OR tbl.Inx2=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with group by min (or max) is could get min from different rows
With this data it makes no difference but maybe this would be safer

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM
(  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Start Date], [End Date] 
                               ORDER     BY [OriginalBeginDate], [OriginalEndDate]) AS rn
     FROM myTable
) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.rn = 1
```